# splitInstallManager.installedLanguages is 0 while running it as apk, it will work fine in aab, but will this work in apk too?

Tags: android, kotlin, apk, locale, dynamic-delivery

splitInstallManager.installedLanguages is 0 while running it as apk

```
 if (!splitInstallManager.installedLanguages.contains(selectedLang) {
        val request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder()
                        .addLanguage(Locale.forLanguageTag(selectedLang))
                        .build()
                    splitInstallManager.startInstall(request)
 }
```